# maven dependency problem when jenkins builds the project

Tags: eclipse, jenkins, maven-3

I have two maven projects, let's say A and B, merely A requires B, reverse is not true. There is no problem when I package A from eclipse. In the "pom.xml" of the project A has a dependency node on B. In jenkins, I configured the project B by adding three goals, which are "clean package install". Therefore, whenever the build of B finishes, it must be exist the archive file of the B in my local maven repository that there is(I checked it). On the other hand, when I build the project A, I got lots of compilation errors "cannot find symbol x". What might be the problem, any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to make sure: You looked into `~jenkins/.m2/repository/`, yes?

Note that `install` always includes `package`, so `clean install` is enough.

But the problem is elsewhere.

1. Check that the versions are the same. Use an exact version number in the dependency of A, not a version range to make sure what it picks up (otherwise, Maven might find a "more suitable" version).
2. If the dependency wasn't there, Maven wouldn't start the compiler (because building the classpath would fail). So the problem is not the JAR file but the content. Make sure that B's JAR file really contains what you expect (`jar tvf` is your friend).
3. Delete the repository on the Jenkins server to make sure there is no old junk in there.

Comment: thank you very much for your interesting Aaron. I found the problem as you stated in 2(content of the jar file): before configuring the jenkins, I copy the source of B to the SVN(first time, I have been developing in my local). However, I miscopied as main and test. When I corrected the folder structure as src/main and src/test, the problem related to building project A has been gone.