# Jenkins build + project dependency issue

Tags: spring, maven, jenkins, dependency-management

I have 2 maven projects let's say A and B. We have used Jenkins for build and deployment purpose. A having dependency over B.

I have an issue over here, whenever I changed something in A only and build it using jenkins, each time I have to build B first otherwise while running the system, Application throws exception like "500 method doesn't found" and the method belongs to B.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7362858/maven-dependency-problem-when-jenkins-builds-the-project?rq=1?

Comment: @gar : I have checked the version number and it was provided exactly. I would require to check the generated JAR file of B. But my question is why I have to build B each time If I made changes in A only? Is it necessary?

Comment: Are the versions snapshots?

Comment: Yes it's a snapshots version.

Comment: Could be something to do with the updatePolicy on the Jenkins repo. The solution to this question may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19180696/maven-not-using-local-repository